# Can numpy einsum() perform outer addition?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

In numpy, we can perform "outer addition" between two vectors `a` and `b` like this:

```
a=np.c_[1,2,3]
b=np.c_[4,5,6]
result=a+b.T # alternatively this can be a.T+b
```

Is it possible to use `einsum` to make the same calculation? Any other fast alternatives? How about if `a` equals `b`?

Comment: I don't think `einsum` can do it (at least without using extra arrays). I can't think of a faster way to do it than the plain sum using broadcasting that you wrote, is it too slow? Since the result is symmetric, you could write an extension that did the minimum possible number of sums.

Comment: You need a vector of ones of the same size as the vectors a and b
I=np.ones(a.shape), something like: `a.T@I + I@I.T`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Another fast alternative to this operation is to use:

```
np.add.outer(a,b)
```